# Page layout works in IE and Firefox, but not Chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have a web page that looks the way I want it to in IE and firefox, but the layout gets changed around in Chrome.

Here is the HTML for the section the is not styling correctly

```
<div class="formInformation">
                    <div class="reason">
                        <h2><b>Why are you requesting a new badge?</b></h2>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblReason" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                            RepeatDirection="Vertical" Width="350px" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="rblReason_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Broken">Broken</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Faded">Faded</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Lost">Lost</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Not Work">Doesn&#39;t Work</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Name Change">Name Change</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Title Change">Title Change</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Dept Change">Dept/Location Change</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                            ID="rfvReason" 
                            runat="server" 
                            ControlToValidate="rblReason"
                            Display="None"
                            ErrorMessage="Select a reason for your request">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                    <div class="reason">
                        <h3><b>Further Information:</b></h3>
                        <h6>(Fields will become visible depending on your selection to the left)</h6>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlLost" runat="server" Visible="False"> 
                            <div class="pnlText"><h5><b>Are you enrolled in QuickCharge?</b></h5></div>
                            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblLost" runat="server"
                                RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="350px">
                                <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                                ID="rfvLost" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="rblLost"
                                Display="None"
                                ErrorMessage="Make a selection for QuickCharge">
                            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDoesNotWork" runat="server" Visible="False">
                            <div class="pnlText"><h5><b>Explain what is not working:</b></h5></div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNotWorking" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                                    Width="225px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                                ID="rfvNotWorking" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtNotWorking"
                                Display="None"
                                ErrorMessage="Describe what is not working">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlNameChange" runat="server" Visible="False">
                            <div class="pnlText"><h4><b>!-For a name change-!</b></h4></div>
                            <div class="pnlText">Please contact HR: 770.836.9517</div>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlTitleChange" runat="server" Visible="False">
                            <div class="pnlText"><h5><b>What is your new title?</b></h5></div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewTitle" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                                    Width="225px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                                ID="rfvNewTitle" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtNewTitle"
                                Display="None"
                                ErrorMessage="Enter your new title">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDeptLocation" runat="server" Visible="False">
                            <div class="pnlText"><h5><b>What is your new Dept/Location?</b></h5></div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewLocation" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                                    Width="225px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                                ID="rfvNewLocation" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtNewLocation"
                                Display="None"
                                ErrorMessage="Enter your new department/location">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="pnlOther" runat="server" Visible="False">
                            <div class="pnlText"><h5><b>Elaborate:</b></h5></div>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtOther" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" 
                                    Width="225px"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
                                ID="rfvOther" 
                                runat="server" 
                                ControlToValidate="txtOther"
                                Display="None"
                                ErrorMessage="Please describe your reason for this request">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here is the CSS to style my page:

```
h2
{
    font-size: large;
}
h3
{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
h4
{
    color: Red;
}
h6
{
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.content
{
    width:950px;
    margin: 5px auto;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:.90em;
    overflow:hidden; 
    background-color:   rgb(255,255,255);   /* Needed for IEs */
    -moz-box-shadow:    0 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         0 3px 5px 3px #ccc;
}
.formText
{
    width: 950px;
    padding-left: 25px;
}
.Headers
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    height: 30px;
}
.employeeInfo
{
    width: 900px;
    height: 85px;
}
.text
{
    float: left;
    width: 85px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    height: 20px;
}
.contacttext
{
    width: 150px;
}
.field
{
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    margin: 0px 123px 20px 0px;
}   
.formInformation
{
    width: 900px;
    border-top: medium dotted #678F00;
}
.reason
{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0px 45px 20px 0px;
    float: left;
}
.special
{
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
    border-top: medium dotted #678F00;
}
.dropDownMenu
{
    width: 375px;
}
#ddlSpecialInstructions
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.sendBadge
{
    width: 900px;
    float: left;
}
.SubmitButton
{
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#btnSubmitRequest
{
    background-color: #00529B;
    color: White;
    font-size: medium;
    font-weight: bolder;
    border: px solid #666666;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

    /*Transition*/
    -webkit-transition: Top 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    transition: All 0.5s ease;

    /*Rounded Corners*/
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;

    /*Gradient*/
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    /*Shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#btnSubmitRequest:hover
{
    background-color: #678F00;
}
```

This is what the page is supposed to look like:
[image]

This is what it looks like in Chrome:
[image]

As you can see, in Chrome the middle section gets re-arranged. Any ideas what is causing it? If you need to see more of my code (HTML and/or C# scripts) just let me know and I will post them.

Thanks in advance!

and like always, If i missed a question that is already on the site, but would correct my problem, please point me to it.

Comment: Definitely post your HTML or a JSFiddle link so that we can see what your markup is. Without that, it's a lot harder to diagnose issues.

Comment: I added the HTML for the section that is not formatting correctly

Comment: no the generated html. not the asp whatever html

Comment: Haven't used jsfiddle before so I have been trying to get it to work. The problem is my script is in C# so jsfiddle is not running it properly. I think johnkavanagh's answer is going to work though.

Comment: I have the solution. I changed one of the "reason" div's to its own name and style it to float left. Then I used the "clear" style that john suggested in his answer. With this combination, it looks the way I want it to in all 3 browsers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very difficult to tell without the outputted markup (what you've included at the moment is the ASP).

However, from the looks of it I'm fairly sure that the issue you're having relates to clearing floats, try tweaking your CSS like this:

```
.reason
{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0px 45px 20px 0px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

Note that this will almost certainly mean all your `.reason` blocks fall one beneath the other (which isn't what you're after).  You might be able to add the clear to `.reason:first-child`, but it all depends on the order of your markup when outputted into the view..

Comment: sorry. I have not used jsfiddle before so I am currently working on getting it set up so i can post the link to my generated code. I will give your suggestion a shot really quick though.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution. The "Further Information" section stays below the radiobuttonlist instead of moving out to the right side, but it looks a lot cleaner and should work just fine. I am going to try to keep tweaking it, but thanks for your assistance!

Comment: @Jason9024 glad that it helped.  I'm not surprised that you're seeing the rest of the layout change too.  Ideally what you need to do is ensure that the parent element of 'Why are you requesting a new badge' has a different class name that you can target specifically.  Otherwise, all elements with `.reason` will clear (leading to them sitting one beneath the other down the page).

Comment: I actually tried that before I saw your comment so seems we ended up on the same page with that part of it. each div now has its own class name to be styled individually!